# Qt + CMake for OSX Bundle: Cocoa Platform Plugin

Tags: macos, qt, cocoa, plugins, cmake

I'm trying to make a bundle for a Qt based application using CMake.

Things seem to be working fine in terms of linkages, but trying to run the app gives me the error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa".

Available platform plugins are: cocoa.
```

I'm not sure what this means as the two lines of output seem conflicting. The directory platforms/ (which contains libqcocoa.dylib) is in MyApp/Contents/Resources/bin/. Note that the MyApp executable is there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the platform library was in the correct position relative to the executable, the libqcocoa library was expecting other Qt libraries to which it was linked to be in specific directories. I used a script with install_name_tool -change commands to modify these paths.

Comment: Could you share it with the community? (=